# Why are 64bit VC++ trigometric function (cmath/math) runtime (hardware) depend

Tags: c++, 64-bit, hardware, trigonometry, math.h

We have been programming the control software for cutting machine since many years. We are developing for Windows only and using Visual Studio 2015 and Qt5.6. Since we plan to distribute our SW as 64bit we have some problems with certain automated test where we compare our output text files vs. a test set.

Tracking down the problem I could see that trigometric (par example sin()) function from  seems to be hw dependent. I am aware that floating point calculation have some uncertainty and every fp types has its own precision. Also I am aware that different cpu have different architecture (fpu, register, etc.) and therefore different behaviour. In x86 we used the floating point model /fp:precise which forced the compiler to build consistent instruction code.
However in x64, the fp models flag are ignored and I can see that the same assembler instruction delivers different results on my i7 laptop and on the build server xeon e5 cpu. See assembler debug output of my attached test code.
[x64 debug on build slave (xeon e5)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Peo1X.png)
vs.
[x64 debug on my laptop (i7)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OX5En.png)
This behaviour we can observe on certain values and it looks like it has to do with how the cpu/fpu handles the floating points. As I understood floating point, precision does not explain this inconsistency (change of last digit). For all calculation we use double. 
In my researches on this topic, I found a lot of stuff about similar issues when win32 compiling, saying that the internal precision used in Intel x86 CPU caused this difference. It could be fixed by setting floating point model /fp:precise. 
However, there seems not a lot of usefull stuff for this on x64.

As we chain up a lot of calculations, the failure propagates itself and becomes more and more significant. Anyway, propably I could fix the problem with changing the automated test and verify the calculation instead of string compare by checking if the results are within certain %-range. This would cause some refactoring in automated test. Furthermore I do not have a good feeling about this whole issue because I can not explain it. Hence I would like know:

- Why this happens with x64 compilation?
- How can I fix it? Compiler settings, using different math library
  (which),...

  ```
  **
  ```

  ## include "stdafx.h"

  ```
  #include <cmath>//"math.h"
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <float.h>
  #include <fstream>
  #include <windows.h>
  #include <tchar.h>
  #include <iomanip>
  #include "../../../../../../../Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/INCLUDE/string"
  //#include "xpfpa.h"
  //#include "Winbase.h"

  using namespace std;

  #pragma fenv_access (on)
  int main()
  {
      string fileName = "";
      // Check windows
  #if _WIN32 || _WIN64
  #if _WIN64
  #define ENVIRONMENT64
  #else
  #define ENVIRONMENT32
  #endif
  #endif

  #ifdef ENVIRONMENT64
      fileName = "X64";
  #else
      fileName = "X86";
  #endif

  #define INFO_BUFFER_SIZE 32767
      TCHAR  infoBuf[INFO_BUFFER_SIZE];
      DWORD  bufCharCount = INFO_BUFFER_SIZE;

      // Get and display the name of the computer.
      if (!GetComputerName(infoBuf, &bufCharCount))
          cout << (TEXT("GetComputerName"));
      //_tprintf(TEXT("\nComputer name:      %s"), infoBuf);

      fileName += "_";
      wstring compNameW(&infoBuf[0]); //convert to wstring
      string compName(compNameW.begin(), compNameW.end()); //and convert to string.
      fileName += compName;
      fileName += ".txt";
      printf("writing %s ... ", fileName.c_str());

      ofstream myfile;
      myfile.open(fileName);

      // Get and display the user name.
      SYSTEM_INFO siSysInfo;

      // Copy the hardware information to the SYSTEM_INFO structure. 

      GetSystemInfo(&siSysInfo);

      // Display the contents of the SYSTEM_INFO structure. 

      myfile << "Hardware information: \n";
      myfile << "  OEM ID: " << siSysInfo.dwOemId << "\n";
      myfile << "  Number of processors: " << siSysInfo.dwNumberOfProcessors << "\n";
      myfile << "  Page size: " << siSysInfo.dwPageSize << "\n";
      myfile << "  Processor type: " << siSysInfo.dwProcessorType << "\n";
      myfile << "  Minimum application address: " << siSysInfo.lpMinimumApplicationAddress << "\n";
      myfile << "  Maximum application address: " << siSysInfo.lpMaximumApplicationAddress << "\n";
      myfile << "  Active processor mask: " << siSysInfo.dwActiveProcessorMask << "\n";
      myfile << "  Prozessor:  " << siSysInfo.dwProcessorType << "\n";

      // Get and display the user name.
      if (!GetUserName(infoBuf, &bufCharCount))
          cout << (TEXT("GetUserName"));
      myfile << "  User name: " << infoBuf << "\n";

      double a = 0.1;
      unsigned int control_word;
      int err;

      // Show original FP control word and do calculation.  
      _controlfp_s(&control_word, 0, 0);


      myfile << "  Original controlWord: " << control_word << "\n";

      //XPFPA_SWITCH_DOUBLE_EXTENDED()

      double angle[572] = { -3.0433482797893871563, -2.8996586887582869174, -2.8085148806578694725, -2.7222381633207075602, -2.6414345623786013029, -2.5663768497517609468, -2.4970681509375158846, -2.4333158242742154442, -2.3748004015428270108, -2.3211319006474169235, -2.2718915465838427359, -2.2266602213456976322, -2.1850363031976076655, -2.1285302693875700619, -2.0782802269842535203, -2.0477766908994761152, -2.005988174897452847, -1.9564494133128236264, -1.9126587369459628896, -1.873457039790540346, -1.8379373648338011016, -1.8053838423691523918, -1.7752255056124330856, -1.7470772220391239671, -1.7205972190315561576, -1.6955175359472745011, -1.6715367216746777057, -1.6370508515541948302, -1.5926855563655908377, -1.5489070972242025004, -1.5045418020355980637, -1.4700559319151131898, -1.4460751176425172826, -1.4209954345582358481, -1.3945154315506684828, -1.3663671479773658035, -1.3362088112206378376, -1.303655288755994679, -1.2681356137992498834, -1.2289339166438335571, -1.1851432402769703778, -1.1356044786923491507, -1.0938159626903252164, -1.0633124266055451468, -1.0130623842022061787, -0.95655635039223041449, -0.9149324322440782753, -0.86970110700594416286, -0.82046075294245079945, -0.76679225204696188634, -0.70827682931560831392, -0.64452450265227778647, -0.5752158038380108529, -0.50015809121119547687, -0.4193544902690680698, -0.33307777293199641866, -0.24193396483144608, -0.098244373800405251917, 0.098246592598153353881, 0.2419391755490098439, 0.33308455926423430338, 0.41936243259553934726, 0.50016675058393433861, 0.57522475996069100113, 0.64453337819516354212, 0.70828530160366642843, 0.76680005532070405483, 0.82046767473287085526, 0.86970698153528180896, 0.9149371328508182355, 0.95655978216497161704, 1.0130637770694810307, 1.0633124266055327123, 1.0938159626903014576, 1.1356044786923560341, 1.1851432402769723762, 1.2289339166438206785, 1.2681356137992438882, 1.3036552887559991198, 1.336208811220639836, 1.3663671479773606965, 1.3945154315506667064, 1.4209954345582336277, 1.4460751176425197251, 1.4700559319151145221, 1.5045418020355980637, 1.5489070972242029445, 1.5926855563655899495, 1.6370508515541959405, 1.6715367216746777057, 1.695517535947273613, 1.7205972190315566017, 1.7470772220391261875, 1.7752255056124304211, 1.8053838423691579429, 1.837937364833798215, 1.8734570397905456751, 1.9126587369459568944, 1.9564494133128234044, 2.0059881748974395244, 2.047776690899469898, 2.0782802269842499676, 2.1285288765203120853, 2.1850328714248230533, 2.2266555207389542304, 2.271885672054521077, 2.321124978856943688, 2.3747925982690616387, 2.4333073519860937139, 2.4970592753946365683, 2.5663678936290801325, 2.6414259030058899747, 2.7222302209942204065, 2.8085080943256390817, 2.8996534780407294818, 3.0433460609916402895, 3.0415926535897748195, 2.8467432816694220321, 2.7523132476245502076, 2.7467432816694219433, 2.7523132476245502076, 2.6647029410266949156, 2.6523132476245501188, 2.6647029410266949156, 2.579683872810047518, 2.5031679332016967265, 2.4296120926562183584, 2.3645064581329338083, 2.302202810172837566, 2.2473823863653894506, 2.1949701996596511222, 2.1488011444494228286, 2.1046019058947580405, 2.0626653414541200604, 1.9944121463226256452, 1.9622126685901970511, 1.9315735849007600322, 1.8804027648941168405, 1.8327714052705215142, 1.7925460686214300665, 1.754537581165664939, 1.7213371485019617335, 1.689539204606653966, 1.6609352327506483604, 1.6332989516959666165, 1.6078954863671903741, 1.5831983785336045667, 1.559875064815740453, 1.5145747859362590493, 1.4707963267948995778, 1.4145747859362591825, 1.370796326794899711, 1.3145747859362590937, 1.2707963267948996222, 1.2145747859362590049, 1.1707963267948997554, 1.1145747859362591381, 1.0707963267948996666, 1.0145747859362592713, 0.97079632679489968883, 0.91457478593625918251, 0.87079632679489971103, 0.81457478593625909369, 0.77079632679489962221, 0.71457478593625911589, 0.67079632679489964442, 1.57079632679489678, 1.559875064815740453, 1.5145747859362788112, 1.4273660152971587856, 1.3817175887740413831, 1.3584530680624329335, 1.3336971672226389796, 1.3083734422622157467, 1.2806808469715929011, 1.2521621173534696059, 1.2202555050878285403, 1.1872246426301178435, 1.1490465849683673127, 1.1090965918582795791, 1.0611898886956727672, 1.0082519403809893088, 0.97944434594385898496, 0.94720024200335728448, 0.87612881663487418571, 0.83708275656112396401, 0.79279150914033258424, 0.74672508224126921128, 0.69421026722450540625, 0.63948440775057413532, 0.57708619545684625152, 0.51202479953317692196, 0.43842472038825908154, 0.36183515262818033431, 0.27688971256307493007, 0.26183515262818035652, 0.27688971256307493007, 0.18902897917758879065, 0.17688971256307489677, 0.18902897917758879065, 0.09649318519633964808, 0.09649318519633964808, -0.099999999999981076249, -0.0035068148036603574713, -0.1999999999999810818, -0.10350681480366033527, -0.2999999999999810596, -0.20350681480366036857, -0.3999999999999810929, -0.30350681480366037412, -0.4999999999999810707, -0.40350681480366035192, -0.59999999999998099298, -0.50350681480366032972, -0.69999999999998097078, -0.60350681480366041853, -0.7999999999999810596, -0.70350681480366039633, -0.89999999999998103739, 8.3266726846886740532e-16, 0.18902897917758879065, 0.096490966398555783057, 0.096490966398555783057, -0.29484508556892286002, -0.38927325484833119607, -0.39484508556892283782, -0.38927325484833119607, -0.47688229101536649956, -0.48927325484833122937, -0.47688229101536649956, -0.56190032315460447521, -0.6384158592678261801, -0.71197152399804841671, -0.77707748130659726193, -0.83938162656427650621, -0.89420287752994354058, -0.94661600989835026354, -0.99278620411343088126, -1.0369866577818922515, -1.0789245264010569603, -1.1471805072672820458, -1.1793799849995274531, -1.2100190686890170966, -1.2611898886956769417, -1.3088212483192762647, -1.3490465849683896948, -1.3870550724240957585, -1.4202555050878500342, -1.4520534489831493641, -1.4806574208391480862, -1.5082937018938800122, -1.5336971672225718777, -1.5583942750562036483, -1.5817175887740404505, -1.6270178676535327345, -1.6707963267949201835, -1.7270178676535326012, -1.7707963267949200503, -1.82701786765353269, -1.8707963267949201391, -1.9270178676535327789, -1.9707963267949200059, -2.0270178676535328677, -2.0707963267949200947, -2.1270178676535325124, -2.1707963267949201835, -2.2270178676535326012, -2.2707963267949198283, -2.32701786765353269, -2.3707963267949203612, -2.4270178676535327789, -2.4707963267949200059, -1.5707963267948961139, -1.5817175887740404505, -1.6270178676535078655, -1.7142266382926427681, -1.7598750648157730492, -1.7831395855273337592, -1.8078954863671412578, -1.8332192113275984635, -1.8609118066181729034, -1.8894305362363632561, -1.9213371485019226093, -1.9543680109596928141, -1.992546068621409594, -2.0324960617315372957, -2.080402764894136336, -2.1333407132088071378, -2.1621483076459360184, -2.1943924115864659186, -2.2654666105872451887, -2.3045139932150995321, -2.3488064494762737056, -2.3948740252348343915, -2.4473897760600111795, -2.5021164762651801894, -2.5645151722833166019, -2.6295769051813611128, -2.7031767943220486039, -2.7797659640671539272, -2.8647103625742662558, -2.879765964067154016, -2.8647103625742662558, -2.9525698094956531747, -2.9647103625742663446, -2.9525698094956531747, -3.0451039059889635219, -3.0433482797893871563, -2.8996586887582869174, -2.8085148806578694725, -2.7222381633206995666, -2.6414345623786075201, -2.5663768497517609468, -2.4970681509375158846, -2.4333158242742309874, -2.3748004015428203495, -2.3211319006473920545, -2.2718915465838374068, -2.2266602213456976322, -2.1850363031976076655, -2.1285302693875727265, -2.078280226984246859, -2.0477766908994703421, -2.0059881748974417448, -1.9564494133128202957, -1.9126587369459586707, -1.8734570397905336847, -1.8379373648338011016, -1.8053838423691548343, -1.7752255056124277566, -1.7470772220391281859, -1.7205972190315563797, -1.6955175359472745011, -1.6715367216746794821, -1.6370508515541968286, -1.5707963267948958919, -1.5045418020355971755, -1.4700559319151131898, -1.4460751176425179487, -1.4209954345582391788, -1.3945154315506675946, -1.3663671479773642492, -1.336208811220639836, -1.3036552887559960112, -1.268135613799243, -1.2289339166438195683, -1.1851432402769703778, -1.1356044786923491507, -1.0938159626903127819, -1.0633124266055475893, -1.0130623842021984071, -0.95655635039219788496, -0.91493243224409481762, -0.86970110700596781061, -0.82046075294242892806, -0.76679225204698586715, -0.70827682931556645851, -0.64452450265226424175, -0.57521580383801340641, -0.50015809121119547687, -0.4193544902690680698, -0.33307777293198825852, -0.24193396483144608, 1.1102230246251565404e-16, 0.2419391755490098439, 0.33308455926423430338, 0.41936243259553834806, 0.50016675058393045283, 0.57522475996068012094, 0.64453337819516354212, 0.70828530160366642843, 0.76680005532072625929, 0.82046767473290371786, 0.869706981535252166, 0.91493713285080491282, 0.95655978216498127598, 1.013063777069502569, 1.0633124266055649088, 1.0938159626903052324, 1.1356044786923513712, 1.1851432402769723762, 1.2289339166438355555, 1.2681356137992485511, 1.303655288755990016, 1.3362088112206353951, 1.366367147977368246, 1.3945154315506660403, 1.4209954345582371804, 1.4460751176425197251, 1.4700559319151145221, 1.5045418020355967315, 1.570796326794896558, 1.6370508515541957184, 1.6715367216746777057, 1.695517535947273613, 1.7205972190315599324, 1.7470772220391261875, 1.7752255056124288668, 1.8053838423691563886, 1.837937364833798437, 1.8734570397905456751, 1.912658736945955118, 1.9564494133128176312, 2.0059881748974395244, 2.0477766908994716744, 2.0782802269842632903, 2.1285288765203058681, 2.1850328714248230533, 2.2266555207389768789, 2.2718856720545121952, 2.3211249788569365826, 2.3747925982690545332, 2.4333073519861243561, 2.4970592753946339037, 2.5663678936290801325, 2.6414259030058704347, 2.7222302209942266238, 2.8085080943256390817, -3.0433482797893871563, -2.8535758972990263871, -2.681152308789283456, -2.5310191384297882067, -2.4034208777577394933, -2.2959698207245691215, -2.2054006923714797317, -2.1285302693875700619, -2.0627648571219414642, -2.005988174897452847, -1.9564494133128236264, -1.9126587369459628896, -1.873457039790540346, -1.8379373648338011016, -1.8053838423691523918, -1.7752255056124330856, -1.7470772220391239671, -1.7205972190315561576, -1.683416728001451812, -1.6370508515541948302, -1.5926855563655908377, -1.5489070972242025004, -1.5045418020355980637, -1.4581759255883395276, -1.4209954345582358481, -1.3945154315506684828, -1.3663671479773658035, -1.3362088112206378376, -1.303655288755994679, -1.2681356137992498834, -1.2289339166438335571, -1.1851432402769703778, -1.1356044786923491507, -1.0788277964678447685, -1.0130623842022061787, -0.93619196121830827728, -0.845622832865261298, -0.7381717758320278655, -0.61057351515998214975, -0.46044034480050533009, -0.28801675629077944096, -0.098244373800405251917, 0.098246592598153353881, 0.28802279786666995509, 0.46044869155366852098, 0.61058246491119927413, 0.73817993253462954595, 0.84562923787566290912, 0.93619602621075082016, 1.0130637770694810307, 1.0788277964678569809, 1.1356044786923560341, 1.1851432402769723762, 1.2289339166438206785, 1.2681356137992438882, 1.3036552887559991198, 1.336208811220639836, 1.3663671479773606965, 1.3945154315506667064, 1.4209954345582336277, 1.458175925588341082, 1.5045418020355980637, 1.5489070972242029445, 1.5926855563655899495, 1.6370508515541959405, 1.683416728001451812, 1.7205972190315566017, 1.7470772220391261875, 1.7752255056124304211, 1.8053838423691579429, 1.837937364833798215, 1.8734570397905456751, 1.9126587369459568944, 1.9564494133128234044, 2.0059881748974395244, 2.0627648571219463491, 2.1285288765203120853, 2.2959634157141572963, -3.0433482797893871563, 2.4034127210551399223, 2.5310101886785765224, 2.8085148806578694725, 2.6811439620361099401, -2.7222381633206995666, 3.0433460609916402895, -2.6414345623786013029, -2.5663768497517609468, -2.4970681509375158846, -2.4333158242742203292, -2.3748004015428318958, -2.3211319006473867255, -2.2718915465838493972, -2.2266602213457034054, -2.1850363031976076655, -2.1285302693875762792, -2.0782802269842486353, -2.0477766908994925465, -2.005988174897452847, -1.9564494133128236264, -1.9126587369459628896, -1.8734570397905410122, -1.8379373648338011016, -1.8053838423691559445, -1.7752255056124308652, -1.7470772220391268537, -1.7205972190315583781, -1.6955175359472745011, -1.6715367216746783718, -1.6370508515541948302, -1.5707963267948970021, -1.5045418020355971755, -1.4700559319151131898, -1.4460751176425175046, -1.4209954345582327395, -1.3945154315506675946, -1.3663671479773642492, -1.3362088112206371715, -1.3036552887559960112, -1.2681356137992492172, 3.0415926535897748195, -1.2289339166438224549, 2.8424367704195603324, -1.1851432402769703778, 2.6647029410267104588, -1.1356044786923491507, 2.497513919224154666, 2.3645064581330341724, -1.0938159626903127819, 2.2431256869789213404, -1.0633124266055316021, -1.0130623842022270509, -0.95655635039219200078, 1.9944121463225683577, -0.86970110700595659736, 1.9315735849007600322, 1.8804027648941168405, 1.8327714052705215142, 1.7925460686214300665, 1.754537581165664939, 1.7213371485019617335, -0.50015809121119547687, 1.689539204606653966, -0.4193544902690680698, -0.33307777293198825852, 1.6069583911871390125, 1.559875064815740453, 1.1102230246251565404e-16, 0.2419391755490098439, 1.4707963267948995778, 1.4145747859362591825, 0.41936243259553834806, 0.50016675058393045283, 1.370796326794899711, 1.3145747859362590937 };
      myfile << "sin(2.4970592753946365683) is " << std::setw(24) << std::setprecision(20) <<  sin(2.4970592753946365683) << "\n";
      double dVal = 0.77079632679489962221;
      double sinValue = sin(dVal);
      myfile << "sin(" << dVal << ") in double is " << std::setw(24) << std::setprecision(20) << sinValue << "\n";

      myfile << "--- Test --- " << "\n";
      for (int i = 0; i < 572; i++)
      {
          myfile << "angle: " << std::setw(24) << std::setprecision(20) << angle[i] << "  ==> sin(angle): " << std::setw(24) << std::setprecision(20) << sin(angle[i]) << "\n";
      }
      std::string input;
      getline(std::cin, input);

      myfile.close();
      return 0;
  }
  ```

Comment: Note that internally the FP registers are/can be 80 bit and when used for intermediate results this can produce unexpected results.

Comment: On x86 (32-bit) the default is to use x87 80-bit floating point. On x64 that is not an option and it uses SSE or AVX instructions instead - 64-bit floating point.

Comment: @Richard: I am aware of that internal 80bit precision, that

Comment: @RichardCritten: I am aware of that internal 80bit precision of the x87fpu. I guess that when we forced the compiler for x86 with /fp:precise that the sw handles the precision on every cpu that same way and we get consistent results. What I could not figure out why we have inconsistent results depending on the cpu with x64 since they should having the same internal precision of 64bit.

Comment: @BoPersson: I was trying to force SSE and AVX, by enable Enhanced Instruction Set. With SSE the results have been the same (inconsistent), the AVX/AVX2 crashes on the elder CPU (xeon). We will have to support much older cores.

Comment: @Mario Disassembly shows that a library routine is being used to compute `sin()`. So without examining the details of the library, we can't find the root cause. Some possibilities: (1) Different (dynamic) library versions linked. (2) Architecture-dependent code paths within the library, e.g. to take advantage of FMA (fused multiply-add) where present (3) Library uses instructions with different implementations across x86 processors, such as `FSIN`. Why does your use case require bit-wise identical `sin()` results across all machines? That is usually not a reasonable requirement.

Comment: @njuffa: Thank you for your inputs. I am not sure that I get all your points right, to:

Comment: @njuffa:
1) When the assembly printscreen are taken - the builds are made on different machine A and B. So that could be a point here, however if I compile and link on machine A and run the executable on A and B I get the same different results. I guess this excludes different libraries as possible reason, or?
2) Good point. How can I see that? I assume that the assembly instruction sin() would directly processed on the hardware and is then the responsibility of the hw manufactorer to deliver consistent result. Am I wrong?

Comment: @njuffa:
3) Yes, I know that. However if I see the assembly instruction sin() on both machine I would expect the same result. Or how can I force the compiler to compile to constistently like it works on x86 with /fp:precise for x64?

Comment: @njuffa:
As math library we use standard cmath library <math.h> on Visual Studio 2015 and VC++-Compiler. About your question about my expectation of bit-wise identical results on sin() - I am investigating why the autotest causes problems since we changed from x86 to x64. In our sw we process graphical data to machine instruction for the cutter. This will be done with several optimisations and calculation which usually includes trignometric function. It looks like that this "failures" respectively differences in the calculations are propagated during this process.

Comment: @njuffa: I am aware that the floating point calculation includes a uncertainty and I will have to modify the tests to tolerate certain deviation. However the end results deviation are much bigger in far away from the precision of the involved data type double. Anyway what I can not dig is why this happen with x64? I guess that there must be something wrong with our compiler settings or library used.

Comment: @Mario Your linked disassembly shows `call sin` which means this is a call to a subroutine `sin`, presumably inside the MSVC math library. The only way to find out what is happening  inside the subroutine is to disassemble the relevant part of the MSVC math library. Any differences in `sin()` results should be minimal (1 or 2 ulp). If this causes major differences in your final results your computation would appear to be ill-conditioned. Consider showing some sample input arguments with the corresponding output results of `sin` on the two machines (all  572 test vectors would be overkill)

Comment: @njuffa: Jeep, you are totally right. There are total different assembly code which will processed on the different hw. Sorry, I did not get your point in the first place, as my assembler knowledge is very basic. There totally different registers and commands involved in the calculation of sin(). In the assembly code there jne/jg... with constant, which I assume are hw versions. On my laptop there v-cmd (like vmulsd), so AVX commands, used whereby the older hw mulsd is used (SSE(2)). So this explains the different results. I assume it does not make sense to deliver the assembly of sin().

Comment: What is bother me, is that I can not align the compiler to a consistent behavior on different hw. As I try to push the compiler to use Enable Enhanced Instruction Set SSE2 the compiler is warning "Command line warning D9002: ignoring unknown option '/arch:SSE2'". Or am I missing compiler switches? I guess I will have to live with that inconsistency and  adjust the tests.